# SQLiteDatabase import Windows Universal

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I'm trying to import an excisting SQLitedatabase in my Windows Universal project.I followed along this [tutorial](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Connect_Universal_App_with_SQLite_Database_and_MVVMLight_Toolkit). Which does just what I want.
However it states:

```
then copy the database with a .sqlite extension to the root of the shared project in your universal app.
```

So I added my excisting databse to the root of my Shared Project

[image]

However when I try the following code I get an IOException the File could not be found.

```
private async Task CopyDatabase()
{
    bool isDatabaseExisting = false;
    try
    {
        StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("FixedCamerasOK.sqlite");
        isDatabaseExisting = true;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        isDatabaseExisting = false;
    }

    if (!isDatabaseExisting)
    {
        StorageFile databaseFile = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync("FixedCamerasOK.sqlite");
        await databaseFile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }
}
```

So where do I place the .sqlite file so it can be found.

Answer (score 0):

Add the File As Content instead as none or empty [image]

Search for the file(FixedCamerasOk.sqlite) in the Installed folder to see if it exists

```
public async Task<bool> DoesDatabaseExist()
    {
        bool dbexists = true;
        try
        {
            var files = Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFilesAsync();

            var retvalues = (from f in await files
                             where f.Name == "FixedCamerasOk.sqlite"
                             select f);

            int count = retvalues.Count();

            if (count > 0)
                return dbexists;
            else
                return false;

                        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            dbexists = false;
        }            
        return dbexists;
    }
```

Comment: Your "does exist" code is incorrect since it looks in the package, not in the data folder (the original question looks in the correct place). Also, I would avoid using LINQ for something as simple as this.

Comment: Yes, WP doesn't expose `TryGetItemAsync` so you're stuck with an exception-based path... although did you benchmark which was more efficient? I say your code is incorrect because the app needs to check if the file is in `ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder` (ie, already been copied). Your suggestion to mark as **Content** is good.

Answer (score 0):

First select your file and in properties select Build Action as Content then open the file like this

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///FixedCamerasOK.sqlite"));
```